# Выбор способа реализации

Tags: vb.net, php, excel, mysql

Добрый день. Требуется совет. Поставлена задача сделать систему, в образовательном учреждении для подсчета и тарификации педагогической нагрузки. 
Имеется в Excel такая таблица, она будет дополняться и будет большая.  Проблема в том, что нужно будет делать выборку по группам, предметам, и д.р., и выводить в отчет (как в Access) и распечатывать. Как проще реализовать? Из вариантов:

1. Excel+Access (Только Access использовать неудобно, т.к. большая таблица получается), но возникает вопрос как делать отчет в Excel...
2. Web (php+mysql), но возникает вопрос как правильно сделать выборку, такую сложную таблицу и выводить на печать сформированный отчет
3. Vb.net + mysql, сделать отчет не составляет сложным, но сделать такую сложную таблицу...

Что посоветуете? Заранее спасибо.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вообще на вкус и цвет тут с товарищами сложно. Думаю тут найдутся специалисты по всем 3м вашим вариантам и будут вам рассказывать, что лучше именно так делать. Выбирать вам конечно.
Что касается 1ого и 3его варианта ничего вам не скажу думаю решаемо без проблем. Что касается второго:

1. организовываете правильно базу
       данных
2. делаете выборки по таблицам и формируете html таблицу.
3. если нужно вывести именно в excel вам поможет решение phpexcel которое
       вашу html таблицу без проблем
       переведет в excel и отдаст в
       желаемом формате.

Comment: Только php медленно работает с Excel файлами ) а в общем да)

Answer (score 1):

> тут найдутся ... и будут вам
> рассказывать, что лучше именно так

Точно :)

У меня вариант 4: *Excel*. Сам-один. И не нужно закидывать гнилыми помидорами :)

Конечно, *Excel* без помощи друга *VBA* никак не обойдется, но при правильной организации данных несколько десятков тысяч строк обрабатываются шустренько.

Признаю, вариант не самый удачный, *Excel+Access* лучше. Но лучше, если с обоими братьями умеешь работать.